# How can I add a home tab or page to my custom lightning app?

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-home-page

I wanted to add Home Page to my custom lightning app.

I tried activating a new home page and assigning it to my app for all profiles, still I am able to see just App Pages and no home page?

Is there any other thing that I need to do to add a home page?

Also, I tried assigning my created custom home page to Sales App and it worked without any issues. The issue is only in custom app[image]

Comment: have you added your newly created home page under  your custom app  navigation items?

Comment: @gauravsharma Thanks, Did not know that. Tried and it worked

Comment: You really should post this as an answer @gauravsharma, this helped me too

Comment: @Stan Alachniewicz  glad it helped.   i have added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show Custom home page in a lightning app, You need to add custom home page   to navigation items of your custom app.